# Module not found: Can't resolve './registerServiceWorker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm having truoble when I'm trying to compile my react application.
When I'm compilie the application I'm recieveing the following error:
`Module not found: Can't resolve './registerServiceWorker`

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"
import {ApolloProvider} from "react-apollo"
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const client = new ApolloClient({
   uri: "http://localhost:4000"
});

ReactDOM.render(
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
registerServiceWorker();
```

I've used create-react-app, and I removed some not used files:

```
App.test.js
App.css
index.css
logo.svg
```

I think that this is the cause of the issue, but I can't locate the source of this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the module should be called `serviceWorker`, not `registerServiceWorker`, although this depends on which version of CRA you used. The most recent version uses:

`import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';`

and then

`serviceWorker.unregister();`

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it helped, please mark the solution as correct :)

Comment: Why doesn't it work like
`import serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';` ?

Comment: `import foo from './foo` works if there's a default export in the file, but if there's multiple exports you can do `import * as foo`.